# How to achieve centered alignment in alignat as in an array with labeled equations?

Tags: align, arrays, alignat

I'm trying to achieve the same alignment in the alignat environment as I have in the array environment. I want this because I'd like to label each equation individually. Here's what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esvect}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c@{\ =\ }c@{\ +\ }c@{\ +\ }c}
\vv{P_{M\!D}} & R_{z}\vv{P_{34}} & R_{xyz}\vv{P_{23}} & \vv{P_{2}}, \\
\vv{P_{M\!I}} & R_{z}\vv{P_{67}} & R_{xyz}\vv{P_{56}} & \vv{P_{5}}, \\
\vv{P_{T\!D}} & R_{y}\vv{P_{910}} & R_{xyz}\vv{P_{89}} & \vv{P_{8}}, \\
\vv{P_{T\!I}} & R_{y}\vv{P_{1213}} & R_{xyz}\vv{P_{1112}} & \vv{P_{11}}.
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\begin{alignat}{6}
\vv{P_{M\!D}} && = & R_{z}\vv{P_{34}} && + & R_{xyz}\vv{P_{23}} && + & \vv{P_{2}}, \label{eq:4}\\
\vv{P_{M\!I}} && = & R_{z}\vv{P_{67}} && + & R_{xyz}\vv{P_{56}} && + & \vv{P_{5}}, \label{eq:5}\\
\vv{P_{T\!D}} && = & R_{y}\vv{P_{910}} && + & R_{xyz}\vv{P_{89}} && + & \vv{P_{8}}, \label{eq:6}\\
\vv{P_{T\!I}} && = & R_{y}\vv{P_{1213}} && + & R_{xyz}\vv{P_{1112}} && + & \vv{P_{11}}. \label{eq:7}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

The first equation shows the desired alignment (centered within each column), but it does not label each line. The second equation labels each line, but the alignment is not as desired.

How can I achieve the alignment of the first equation but with individual labels for each equation as in the second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `IEEEeqnarray` from `IEEEtrantools`. The column type `c` stands for “normal object centered”, `C` for “binary operation or relation centered”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{esvect}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c@{\ =\ }c@{\ +\ }c@{\ +\ }c}
\vv{P_{M\!D}} & R_{z}\vv{P_{34}} & R_{xyz}\vv{P_{23}} & \vv{P_{2}}, \\
\vv{P_{M\!I}} & R_{z}\vv{P_{67}} & R_{xyz}\vv{P_{56}} & \vv{P_{5}}, \\
\vv{P_{T\!D}} & R_{y}\vv{P_{910}} & R_{xyz}\vv{P_{89}} & \vv{P_{8}}, \\
\vv{P_{T\!I}} & R_{y}\vv{P_{1213}} & R_{xyz}\vv{P_{1112}} & \vv{P_{11}}.
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{c C c C c C c}
\vv{P_{M\!D}} & = & R_{z}\vv{P_{34}}   & + & R_{xyz}\vv{P_{23}}   & + & \vv{P_{2}}, \label{eq:4}\\
\vv{P_{M\!I}} & = & R_{z}\vv{P_{67}}   & + & R_{xyz}\vv{P_{56}}   & + & \vv{P_{5}}, \label{eq:5}\\
\vv{P_{T\!D}} & = & R_{y}\vv{P_{910}}  & + & R_{xyz}\vv{P_{89}}   & + & \vv{P_{8}}, \label{eq:6}\\
\vv{P_{T\!I}} & = & R_{y}\vv{P_{1213}} & + & R_{xyz}\vv{P_{1112}} & + & \vv{P_{11}}. \label{eq:7}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very mucho! :)

Answer (score 1):

Speaking for myself, I can see no compelling reason for centering rather than left-aligning the contents of the implicit columns. Incidentally, with proper syntax, the `alignat` environment should take `3` rather than `6` as its argument.

I can see a huge advantage, in terms of readability, of letting the arrows span just the letter "P" -- see equations 6 thru 9 below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,esvect}
\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathit{#1}} % 'vn' is short for 'variable name'

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{r @{{}={}} l @{{}+{}} l @{{}+{}} l}
\vv{P_{\vn{MD}}} & R_{z}\vv{P_{34}}   & R_{\vn{xyz}}\vv{P_{23}}   & \vv{P_{2}}, \\
\vv{P_{\vn{MI}}} & R_{z}\vv{P_{67}}   & R_{\vn{xyz}}\vv{P_{56}}   & \vv{P_{5}}, \\
\vv{P_{\vn{TD}}} & R_{y}\vv{P_{910}}  & R_{\vn{xyz}}\vv{P_{89}}   & \vv{P_{8}}, \\
\vv{P_{\vn{TI}}} & R_{y}\vv{P_{1213}} & R_{\vn{xyz}}\vv{P_{1112}} & \vv{P_{11}}.
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\begin{alignat}{3}
\vv{P_{\vn{MD}}} &= R_{z}\vv{P_{34}}   && + R_{\vn{xyz}}\vv{P_{23}}   && + \vv{P_{2}}, \label{eq:2}\\
\vv{P_{\vn{MI}}} &= R_{z}\vv{P_{67}}   && + R_{\vn{xyz}}\vv{P_{56}}   && + \vv{P_{5}}, \label{eq:3}\\
\vv{P_{\vn{TD}}} &= R_{y}\vv{P_{910}}  && + R_{\vn{xyz}}\vv{P_{89}}   && + \vv{P_{8}}, \label{eq:4}\\
\vv{P_{\vn{TI}}} &= R_{y}\vv{P_{1213}} && + R_{\vn{xyz}}\vv{P_{1112}} && + \vv{P_{11}}.\label{eq:5}
\end{alignat}

\begin{alignat}{3}
\vv{P}_{\!\vn{MD}} &= R_{z}\vv{P}_{\!34}   && + R_{\vn{xyz}}\vv{P}_{\!23}   && + \vv{P}_{\!2}, \label{eq:6}\\
\vv{P}_{\!\vn{MI}} &= R_{z}\vv{P}_{\!67}   && + R_{\vn{xyz}}\vv{P}_{\!56}   && + \vv{P}_{\!5}, \label{eq:7}\\
\vv{P}_{\!\vn{TD}} &= R_{y}\vv{P}_{\!910}  && + R_{\vn{xyz}}\vv{P}_{\!89}   && + \vv{P}_{\!8}, \label{eq:8}\\
\vv{P}_{\!\vn{TI}} &= R_{y}\vv{P}_{\!1213} && + R_{\vn{xyz}}\vv{P}_{\!1112} && + \vv{P}_{\!11}.\label{eq:9}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```